# Pattern for trying different methods when exception is thrown

Tags: design-patterns, exception

Here's a question to expose my lack of experience: I have a method **DoSomething()** which throws an exception if it doesn't manage to do it cleanly. If it fails, I try the less accurate method **DoSomethingApproximately()** several times in the hope that it will find a sufficiently good solution; if this also fails I finally call **DoSomethingInaccurateButGuaranteedToWork()**. All three are methods belonging to this object.

Two questions: first, is this (admittedly ugly) pattern acceptable, or is there a more elegant way?

Second, what is the best way to keep track of how many times I have called **DoSomethingApproximately()**, given that it is likely to throw an exception? I am currently keeping a variable iNoOfAttempts in the object, and nesting try blocks... this is horrible and I am ashamed.

Comment: Yes; I assume that most solutions should be fairly language-agnostic, as long as exception-handling is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use exceptions for control flow of your application.

In your case I'd bunch the three methods together into a single method and have it return which particular approach succeeded, maybe with an enum or something like that.

Comment: I disagree. if DoSomethingApproximately() and DoSomethingThatAlwaysWorks() are actually error-handling functions, then exceptions may very well the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: Exceptions are to be thrown in unexpected situations, not in expected errors. Of course there are exceptions to this rule as well.

Comment: Yes, of course. We must assume that DoSomething() does what it's supposed to do, unless something unexpected happens... ;)

Comment: No, we must assume nothing. The questioner even seems to expect that the method will fail...

Comment: Beyond that, you have to be careful you aren't hiding exceptions which are actual problems and not 'expected' problems. Regardless, +1 don't use exceptions for flow control.

Comment: I only expect it to fail very rarely. But I take the point about flow control.

Answer (score 2):

Return an error code instead of throwing an exception.

If the ways those methods fail do throw exceptions, catch them all in the same method and take appropriate action, like increasing a counter and returning an error code.

```
   bool result = DoSomething();
   while (!result && tries < MAX_TRIES) {
       result = DoSomethingApproximately(); //This will increment tries
       if (tries > THRESHOLD) {
           result = DoSomethingThatAlwaysWorks();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about (pseudocode):

```
try{ return doSomething(); }
catch(ExpectedException) { ...not much here probably...}

for(i = 0 to RETRIES){
try{ return doSomethingApproximately; }
catch(ExpectedException) { ...not much here probably...}
}

doSomethingGuaranteed();
```

Addendum:

I strongly recommend that you do not use special return values, because that means that every single user of the function has to know that some of the return values are special. Depending on the range of the function, it may be sensible to return an ordinary part of the range that can be dealt with normally, e.g. an empty collection. Of course, that may make it impossible to distinguish between failure, and the "right" answer being the empty collection (in this example).

Comment: I sometimes like to have a parameter to allows the caller to indicate whether the common failure modes should be indicated via exception or return code. Consider something like "log onto server X with credential Y". If the caller expects that the attempt may fail (e.g. if it has a list of servers, and will try until it succeeds) having the method throw an exception isn't helpful. On the other hand, if code is expecting a login to simply work, throwing an exception may eliminate the need for client-side error checking on the attempt, if the exception thrown will be one the client can catch.

Answer (score 2):

Go the whole function pointers in a structure route. Just to spice it up, I'll use a Queue and some LINQ.

```
Queue<Action> actions = new Queue<Action>(new Action[] {
   obj.DoSomething,
   obj.DoSomethingApproximately,
   obj.DoSomethingApproximately,
   obj.DoSomethingApproximately,
   obj.DoSomethingApproximately,
   obj.DoSomethingGuaranteed
});

actions.First(a => {
   try {
      a();
      return true;
   } catch (Exception) {
      return false;
   }
});
```